# get row of Cell in Table View Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

there is a tableView Cell and a Text field Inside it . the question it is how can get indexPath.row of table View in text field Delegates . Exactly in textFieldDidEndEditing .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `UITableView.indexPath(for:)`.  It "Returns an index path representing the row and section of a given table-view cell" and the index path contains the `row`.

For example, `self.tableView.indexPath(for:myCell)`